# In the basic Fraenkel (permutation) model, any functions from $\omega$ to $P(A)$ has finite range.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Working within the Basic Fraenkel (permutation) model. As defined in Jech's axiom of choice.

Let $A$ be the set of atoms.

I want to show that any function  $f: \omega \rightarrow P(A)$ has finite range. But honestly I am really stuck, any help or insights is well appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Here is an indirect way, which might not reveal much on the Fraenkel model itself, but it is more informative in other ways.

> **Theorem 1.** (Kuratowski) There is a surjection from $X$ onto $\omega$ if and only if there is an injection from $\omega$ into $\mathcal P(X)$.

This one has a bit of a difficult proof, so I will skip it here.

Recall that a set $A$ is amorphous if it cannot be written as a disjoint union of two infinite sets.

> **Theorem 2.** If $A$ is amorphous, then any function from $A$ into a set which can be well-ordered has a finite range.

*Proof.* Suppose not, then by the basic properties of well-ordered sets we may assume that the function is onto $\omega$. Now take the pre-image of the odd integers and the even integers, and these must be two disjoint infinite subsets.

*Remark.* We can extend the proof to "linearly ordered", but conceptually it is easier to prove it about well-ordered sets, and it is enough for our case.

> **Theorem 3.** In the basic Fraenkel model the set of atoms is amorphous.

*Proof.* If $B\subseteq A$ is an infinite set, let $E$ be a finite set such that whenever $\pi\colon A\to A$ is a permutation satisfying $\pi\restriction E=\operatorname{id}$, $\pi(B)=B$.

If $a\in A\setminus B$, but $a\notin E$, then we may take any $b\in B\setminus E$ and consider the $2$-cycle, $\pi=(a\ b)$. Easily, $\pi\restriction E=\operatorname{id}$ and $p(B)\neq B$. Therefore $A\setminus B\subseteq E$, and thus finite.

> **Corollary**. There is no injection from $\omega$ into $\mathcal P(A)$ in Fraenkel's basic model, where $A$ is the set of atoms.

*Proof.* There is no surjection from $A$, the set of atoms, in Fraenkel's model onto $\omega$, and therefore no injection from $\omega$ into $\mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you show, e.g. that there is no injective function $\omega\to A.$ Assume $f:\omega\to P(A)$ has infinite range, and let $E$ be an arbitrary finite subset of $A.$ Since the range is infinite, you can find two atoms $a_1,a_2$ such that $a_1,a_2\notin E$ and there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $a_1\in f(n)$ but $a_2\notin f(n).$ So the permutation that swaps $a_1$ and $a_2$ fixes $E$ but does not fix $f.$ Thus $E$ is not a support for $f,$ and since $E$ was arbitrary, $f$ is not symmetric.